# How to install Microsoft Access Runtime 2013 32-Bit Silently?

Tags: wix

I am trying to install Microsoft Access Runtime 2013 32-Bit silently using `quiet` property, but still it is showing the Installation UI window and asking to accept EULA. Earlier I was using Access Database Engine 2007 which was getting installed silently with `quiet` command. What am I missing? I am using below code to install it silently:

```
<ExePackage DisplayName="Microsoft Access Runtime 2013"
    SourceFile="..\Prerequisites\Microsoft Access x86 Runtime 2013\AccessRuntime_x86_en-us.exe"
    InstallCommand="/quiet"
    InstallCondition="NOT ACCESS_ENGINE=5"
    Permanent="yes"
    Compressed ="yes"
  />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please edit your post to add your "code" and do not post it in the comment section?

Comment: I've added my code inside body section but I'm not able to see it here...

Comment: Your edit or someone's else edit is awaiting approval. Your code will be visible after it is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the following tips from [**itninja.com**](http://www.itninja.com) (formerly appdeploy.com):

- **https://www.itninja.com/software/microsoft/access-runtime/2013-14**
- **https://www.itninja.com/question/packaging-access-runtime-2013**

Essentially:

1. Extract files using **`AccessRuntime_x86_en-us.exe /extract:ExtractedFiles`**.
2. Create a **`config.xml`** as described in the links above. Let me just duplicate it here in case the links go dead. And obviously update the paths for your purpose and for your environment:

   ```
   <Configuration Product="AccessRT">
   <Display Level="None" CompletionNotice="no" SuppressModal="yes" AcceptEula="yes" />
   <Logging Type="standard" Path="C:\Windows\Temp\" Template="Microsoft_Access_2013_Runtime_Setup(*).log" />
   <COMPANYNAME Value="Company Name" />
   <Setting Id="SETUP_REBOOT" Value="Never" />
   </Configuration>
   ```
3. Install with **`setup.exe /config config.xml`**.

Comment: When we extract the Exe, we are getting multiple Files and Folders. How can we include all of them to an Exepackage in WIX Bundle?
I tried with including only setup.exe (that got from extraction) in the Source File but it still failing, during the installation.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it seems you need to add each file you want to include as a **`<Payload />`** element underneath the **`ExePackage`** element. I am afraid I don't have the time to dig up a sample now, but maybe try **`github.com`** and search for **`ExePackage`** and **`Payload`**? Alternatively I suppose you could wrap it yourself in a 7-Zip self-extractor, but that would be a dreadful mess - wouldn't it?

Comment: Personally I would hope you could distribute the extracted files via **SCCM** or another distribution system - if you have one? (but I guess you don't). The customization of Office has always been weird. I wouldn't be surprised if there is a tool in there to wrap it all in a new EXE for you - with a simple command line.

Comment: [The closest I could find in a hurry](https://github.com/python-doc-ja/cpython-doc-catalog/blob/8874342cf332c3aa3d845155cc4b41b00c2d9e9d/Tools/msi/bundle/packagegroups/packageinstall.wxs).